# apple cpp breaks macro-parameter pasting

Tags: c++, c, clang, apple-developer

Compile the following test.cpp

```
# define TopLevelProject X11

#define Concat3(a,b,c) a/**/b/**/c

# define ProjectRulesFile Concat3(<,TopLevelProject,.rules>)

#include ProjectRulesFile
```

**cpp -I. *test.cpp***

The expected behavior is that an include statement be generated

```
# 1 "test.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.cpp"
# 10 "test.cpp"
# 1 "./X11.rules" 1
# 11 "test.cpp" 2



# 1 "./X11.rules" 1
# 15 "test.cpp" 2
```

Note that the line
**"./X11.rules"**
is indeed output

However, apple's clang cpp gives the output

```
# 1 "test.cpp"
# 1 "<built-in>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 3
# 361 "<built-in>" 3
# 1 "<command line>" 1
# 1 "<built-in>" 2
# 1 "test.cpp" 2


test.cpp:7:10: fatal error: ' X11 .rules' file not found
#include ProjectRulesFile
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:5:35: note: expanded from macro 'ProjectRulesFile'
# define ProjectRulesFile       Concat3(<,TopLevelProject,.rules>)
                                ~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:3:24: note: expanded from macro 'Concat3'
#define Concat3(a,b,c) a/**/b/**/c
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~

1 error generated.
```

Note the malformed filename **' X11 .rules'**

Apple's cpp inserted a space before the first parameter, and another between the second and third parameters of the Concat3 macro.

All versions of gcc, clang, and the msdev tools perform the proper text-substitution.

But

All versions of apple's cpp, such as those distributed by xcode, have this bug.

**Is there some sort of macro parameter concatenation scheme I could use to write the **Concat3** macro so that it works under apple's cpp?**

Thanks

Comment: `# define ProjectRulesFile <TopLevelProject.rules>` substitutes for `TopLevelProject` and includes the file as desired. Do you need to handle the `<` or `.rules>` with `Concat3`? Why?

Comment: `a/**/b/**/c` doesn't do what you think it does. It's equivalent to `a b c`. I'm surprized it works at all on GCC and the vanilla Clang.

Comment: @eric-postpischil this is a mini-example taken from a larger code-base (the imake config-file set) and the Concat3 macro is invoked many times with many using the same syntax I posted.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I assure you, the latest plain-clang still supports this. The latest apple-clang's cpp, which is the same version number as the plain-clang, does not work. Is there maybe a way of obtaining the same effect with other strategies?

Comment: `Concat3(a,b,c) a/**/b/**/c` is an ancient, pre-standard, long deprecated method of concatenating stuff. It doesn't works on anything modern.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. it works with the latest clang and gcc and msvc

Comment: It doesn't work with clang [see here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e5a8da5cffca13c4)  or msvc [see here](https://godbolt.org/z/xndEve). Apple's compiler is clang. With gcc you just got lucky because "6.10.2/4 The method by which a sequence of preprocessing tokens
between a `<` and a `>` preprocessing token pair or a pair of `"` characters is combined into a
single header name preprocessing token is implementation-defined." This method of concatenation MAY work today with gcc ONLY when concatenating a header name, but not when concatenating anything else.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat what is "vanilla clang"? My clang install on Linux rejects it. Maybe it's something that uses the gcc preprocessor?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I was referring to the regular Clang, as opossed to Apple Clang. Shouldn't have taken OP's word for it, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Concat3(a,b,c) a/**/b/**/c` is an ancient, pre-standard, long deprecated method of concatenating stuff. It generally doesn't work on anything modern (that is, past 1990 or so). It *may* work specifically for concatenating header names with *some* compilers, because that's an implementation-defined area.

> 6.10.2/4 The method by which a sequence of preprocessing tokens between a `<` and a `>` preprocessing token pair or a pair of `"` characters is combined into a single header name preprocessing token is implementation-defined.

Concatenating anything that is not a header name with this method is out of the question.

There is NO standard way to concatenate a header name that works for all compilers. The standard trick

```
#define CAT(a,b) CAT2(a,b)
#define CAT2(a,b) a ## b
```

does not work if the result is not a valid preprocessing token, which most header names aren't.